# Jpgraph: Show all text ticks on X axe

Tags: php, jpgraph

**I'm trying to show all my text ticks on the xaxis on my graph generated by jpgraph**. However, the best I can do is to show one on two.

I'm at

```
$graph->SetTickDensity(TICKD_NORMAL,TICKD_NORMAL);
```

even when I go `DENSE` it does not make a difference.

```
$graph->SetTickDensity(TICKD_DENSE,TICKD_NORMAL);
```

I tried to make the graph bigger or put some angle on my ticks but that did not help either.

Any clue on how I can display all the ticks of my xaxis?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

I add an array with all my TickLabels and I counted the number of entries in my data array:

```
$Ticklabels = array() // An array with the same number of element as the $datax array
$count = count($datax);
```

Then I made an array with from 0 to `$count`.

```
$x=0;
foreach ($x < $count){
array_push($Tickposition, $x);
$x++;};
```

Then I use the `SetMajTickPositions()` class.

```
$graph->xaxis->SetMajTickPositions($Tickposition, $ticklabels);
```

Again, it is really important to have the same number of element in the `$Tickposition` and `$ticklabels` or JPgraph will return an error.